# make tab a modifier key

Tags: windows, autohotkey

Is it possible to set TAB as a modifier key?

I want to bind `tab-h/j/k/l` to vim-style movement keys.

Seems there is no mention of adding **additional** hotkeys in the [Hotkeys documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols) page.

This simple autohotkey script doesn't work:

```
Tab::RCTRL
RCTRL::
    MsgBox Hello world
return
```

Googling `windows create  modifier keys` yields [nothing](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/6200870933).

*I am already using CapsLock as CTRL, so this question is not about CapsLock.